Selenium cannot send keys to youtube searchbox
Recently I started working a bit with selenium and encountered the problem that i could not send keys to the youtube searchbox with the following code:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
service = Service(executable_path="chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
driver.get("https://youtube.com")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "ytd-searchbox")))
input_element = driver.find_element (By.CLASS_NAME,"ytd-searchbox")
input_element.send_keys("some text"+Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(100)

The name of the class should be correct because the searchbox gets highlighted when i run the function:
input_element.click()

The terminals output is:

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:61618/devtools/browser/a9e75182-8834-47ba-9b5d-94dad187f4d4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\noahm\Desktop\Vs_Code\programming\creativestuff\login_bot.py", line 13, in <module>
    input_element.send_keys("some text"+Keys.ENTER)
  File "C:\Users\noahm\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 231, in send_keys
    self._execute(
  File "C:\Users\noahm\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 395, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\noahm\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 354, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\noahm\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response  
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=126.0.6478.127)
Stacktrace:
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6B4ECEEA2+31554]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6B4E47ED9]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6B4D08559]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6B4D51D73]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6B4D4FEDB]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6B4D7D02A]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6B4D4BA76]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6B4D7D240]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6B4D9C977]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6B4D7CDD3]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6B4D4A33B]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6B4D4AED1]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6B51D8B1D+3217341]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6B5225AE3+3532675]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6B521B0E0+3489152]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6B4F7E776+750614]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6B4E5375F]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6B4E4EB14]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6B4E4ECA2]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6B4E3E16F]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFA88B1257D+29]
        RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFA8954AF28+40]




The same output emerged when i tried the code from this website:
text
I would appreciate your help

It looks like there are at least 9 nodes that return with the selector ".ytd-searchbox".
(using chrome inspector)
> location.href
'https://www.youtube.com/'
> document.querySelectorAll(".ytd-searchbox")
NodeList(9) [form#search-form.style-scope.ytd-searchbox, div#container.style-scope.ytd-searchbox, yt-icon#search-icon.style-scope.ytd-searchbox, input#search.ytd-searchbox, div#search-clear-button.style-scope.ytd-searchbox, ytd-button-renderer.style-scope.ytd-searchbox, button#search-icon-legacy.style-scope.ytd-searchbox, yt-icon.style-scope.ytd-searchbox, tp-yt-paper-tooltip.style-scope.ytd-searchbox]

Generally it's not a good idea to match on the class attribute unless you have to.
Oddly enough, in the case of YouTube's Search Box, "ID" isn't even unique 
Try matching on this CSS Selector instead:
...

input_element = driver.find_element (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#search")
input_element.send_keys("some text"+Keys.ENTER)

...

